# How to create a new instance Serializable class by reflection in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection, serializable

Stub object for testing purposes fails to create via reflection:

```kotlin
internal fun <T : ParentThingy> KClass<in T>.random(): T {
    val createViaConstructor = constructors.first()
    val args = createViaConstructor.parameters.associateWith { param ->
        when (param.type) {
            Int::class.starProjectedType -> gen.primitive().int()
            // other options omitted for brevity
            else -> error("$param not supported, it's type ${param.type}")
        }
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return createViaConstructor.callBy(args) as T
}
```

becase of:

```
parameter #2 serializationConstructorMarker of fun `<init>`(kotlin.Int, kotlinx.serialization.internal.SerializationConstructorMarker?): some.child.Thingy not supported, it's type kotlinx.serialization.internal.SerializationConstructorMarker?
```

-- the class has `@Serializable` annotation. Reflection with a factory method works fine. Any ideas how to make reflection work with a primary constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the primary constructor, there is a property to get that - [`primaryConstructor`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/primary-constructor.html).

```
val createViaConstructor = primaryConstructor ?: error(
    "$this does not have a primary constructor"
)
```

When you use the `constructors` property instead, the constructors are not guaranteed to be in any order. You can't just assume that the first one is the primary constructor.

It turns out that `@Serializable` generates a secondary constructor with an extra `SerializationConstructorMarker` parameter, presumably that's the constructor that will be called during deserialisation. The extra parameter is probably just there so that the two constructors have a different JVM signature. In any case, `first()` ends up returning the generated constructor, not the one you want.

Comment: Actually primaryConstructor is Klass' property, `constructors` in `constructors.primaryConstructor` is excessive. Anyway, you saved my day!